# Is it possible to send body in GET request using rest-assured

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured on my test automation project and in one of my calls I need to send body in GET request, is that possible to do it in rest-assured and if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

No. GET requests don't have a body. They don't need one, because with a GET request you don't send data to the server, GET requests are for GETting data from the server. Take a look at PUT and POST requests to send data to the server.

Comment: I agree, but that's how that endpoint works, and I can't change it, all I can do is get the data from response and for that I need to send the body, do you have any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: use query or path parameters

Comment: @harmatii1 the endpoint is not HTTP compliant. You have made your own protocol so you’ll need to write your own tools…